# Stochastic matrix of three states which has Boltzmann distribution as equilibrium

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, computational-physics

In my course on computational physics we are given the following exercise:

[image: The exercise as given to us]

I already solved the first and second part, but I'm stuck at the third. I've tried matrix multiplication of the stochastic matrix and the equilibrium state vector and trying to solve the system of equations, but apart from finally understanding where the characteristic equation of a matrix comes from, this has bore no success. Then I tried to manually "guess" the transition rates using the fact that the elements in a column should sum to one and the equations I calculated previously, but I found myself running in circles.

Any nudge in the right direction is appreciated, I still want to learn from this exercise and sole it myself as much as possible, but I am really stuck.

Answer (score 0):

The system satisfies the equation:
$$
\dot{p}_i(t) = \sum_j M_{ij}p_j(t),
$$
where $M_{ij}$ is the stochastic matrix. Note that this matrix satisfies constrain that
$$
\sum_i \dot{p}_i(t) = \sum_{i,j} M_{ij}p_j(t) = 0
$$
for any value of $p_i$-s, so that $\sum_i M_{ij}=0$.

The stationary distribution is obtained by solving
$$
\sum_j M_{ij}p_j = 0.
$$
For three levels this can be easily done explicitly. We further impose the condition that the resulting stationary $p_i$-s are given by the Boltzmann distribution. It is easy to see that the solution obtained this way is more general than the one obtained when we impose an additional detailed balance constraint on the matrix, $M_{ij}/M_{ji}=e^{-\beta(E_i-E_j)}$.

Comment: I do not exactly see how the system satisfies the first equation. Isn't $\sum_j M_{ij} p_j = p_i (t+\Delta t)$ instead of $p_i(t + \Delta t) - p_i(t)$?

Comment: It depends on how you define matrix $M$, but the two equations are related. If you want a more specific answer, it is better that you give in your questions more details about your resoning and the equations that you use.